# .index() doesn't seem to work for dynamically created collapsible listviews

Tags: jquery, listview, dynamically-generated

### Hi Stackoverflow,

I am trying to get the number of the element clicked in a listview as follows :

```
$('#list_task0').on('click', $('li'),function( event, ui ) {


    //alert($('#list_task0:last-child').text());
    //alert($('#list_task0'.size());

    day_to_edit = $(this).index();

    });
```

The list is generated as follows:

```
$('<div>').attr({'id':'task_'+task_count+'','data-role':'collapsible'}).html('<h2>Task : '+task_name+'</h2><h1><ul id=list_task'+task_count+' data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-icon="false"></ul></h1>').appendTo('#task_recapitulator');
    $('<li>').attr({}).html('<a href="#">&nbsp;Project : '+curr_proj+'</a>').appendTo('#list_task'+task_count+'');
    $('<li>').attr({'data-theme':'a'}).html('<a href="#">&nbsp;Shift/On Call : '+curr_shift+'</a>').appendTo('#list_task'+task_count+'');


       for(var j=0;j<7;j++) {
        $('<li>').attr({'data-theme':''+theme(j)+''}).html('<a href="#">&nbsp;Day '+(j+1)+' hours : <span class="ui-li-count">'+hours[j]+'</span></a>').appendTo('#list_task'+task_count+'');   

       }

    task_count++;


    $('#new').trigger('create');
```

What am I missing? The index returned is 0 every time, and the created list seems to be of size 1 and have only one child. However, if I inspect it, it seems to be a regular list with the li tags properly nested inside... I thought .appendTo created a new child?

P.S.: I am only listening to the clicks on #list_task0 for debugging purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use li instead of $(li),and also **this** is not string it is object ,remove double quotes

```
$('#list_task0').on('click', 'li',function( event, ui ) {
    day_to_edit = $(this).index();
});
```

Comment: Thank you all; the 'this' was a typo I made when asking the question; however, it worked when using li instead of $(li).  Wish i could upvote other answers but it seems new members have alot of restrictions here =P

Comment: Well @user3644907 you don't have a restriction to mark the answer as correct  :p

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `day_to_edit = $('this').index();` which means `this` is a tag type but actually it should be an instance of current html element.

So call it like :

```
day_to_edit = $(this).index();
```

Comment: this index is with respect to all children present under same parent. please post me jsfiddle so that I can help you better on this.

Comment: I am sorry, commented under the wrong post. It works now; I would love to understand the function mechanisms better but I am a bit in a rush currently so it isn't possible atm.